# Oreilly XMPP example codes

Tags: xmpp

I was reading this book Oreilly XMPP The definitive Guide

Theres and example code in chapter 2 for an EchoBot

I want to know how i can test this code...

def main():

```
bot = EchoBot("echobot@wonderland.lit/HelloWorld", "mypass")
bot.run()
```

class EchoBot(object):

```
def __init__(self, jid, password):
    self.xmpp = sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP(jid, password)
    self.xmpp.add_event_handler("session_start", self.handleXMPPConnected)
    self.xmpp.add_event_handler("message", self.handleIncomingMessage)

def run(self):
    self.xmpp.connect()
    self.xmpp.process(threaded=False)

def handleXMPPConnected(self, event):
    self.xmpp.sendPresence(pstatus="Send me a message")

def handleIncomingMessage(self, message):
    self.xmpp.sendMessage(message["jid"], message["message"])
```

ive installed sleekxmpp, created an account on jabber.org and replaced echobot@wonderland.lit/HelloWorld with myusername@jabber.org/HelloWorld and mypass with mypassword

But when i run this code... it doesnt seem to do anything. it jus terminates.
Is there anything im missing?

Comment: Its suppose to echo back whatever message you send to myusername@jabber.org. Login to jabber.org with another JID and start and a chat with myusername

Answer (score 1):

This example code does not work with new version of SleekXMPP library, because **API has been changed**.

Last line of your bot should be:

```
    self.xmpp.sendMessage(message["from"], message["body"])
```

The author of SleekXMPP library explains changes required in example code here: https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/wiki/XMPP%3A-The-Definitive-Guide

Answer (score 0):

In order to test the echo bot, you can open another Jabber Client (Psi or Kopete for example), add the echo bot to your roster and then you can chat with it like you would in any other IM scenario, only the echo bot will respond with the message that you sent it.

But be sure to visit https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/wiki/XMPP%3A-The-Definitive-Guide to see the most update version of the the books examples.